# Vector recycling is not working when assigning to data.frame

Tags: r

I'm banking on vector recycling to populate an R dataframe with simulated data, but the behavior doesn't match expectations.

I can run this with success:

```
store.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=5, nrow=2080))
names(store.df)<-c("storeNum", "upc_id", "Week_id", "weekday_id", "units")
sn<-c(60, 89, 105, 170, 1240)
store.df$storeNum <- sn
wid<-c(201531,201532,201533,201534,201535,201536,201537,201538)
store.df$Week_id <- wid
```

To achieve this:

```
summary(store.df)

        storeNum       upc_id           Week_id       weekday_id      units        
 Min.   :  60.0   Mode:logical   Min.   :201531   Mode:logical   Mode:logical  
 1st Qu.:  89.0   NA's:2080      1st Qu.:201533   NA's:2080      NA's:2080     
 Median : 105.0                  Median :201535                                
 Mean   : 332.8                  Mean   :201535                                
 3rd Qu.: 170.0                  3rd Qu.:201536                                
 Max.   :1240.0                  Max.   :201538
```

But, if I run with the last two lines seen here:

```
store.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=5, nrow=2080))
names(store.df)<-c("storeNum", "upc_id", "Week_id", "weekday_id", "units")
sn<-c(60, 89, 105, 170, 1240)
store.df$storeNum <- sn
wid<-c(201531,201532,201533,201534,201535,201536,201537,201538)
store.df$Week_id <- wid
wdid<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
store.df$weekday_id <- wdid
```

then I get this error:

```
wdid<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
store.df$weekday_id <- wdid
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "weekday_id", value = c(1, 2, 3, 4,  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 2080
```

Why can I not recycle the `wdid` vector into `store.df` with the same success as I had with the first two statements (`store.df$storeNum <- sn` & `store.df$Week_id <- wid`)?

Is it possible to make this succeed without converting `wdid` to a vector of the same length as `store.df`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because 2000 is not divisible by 7.  Partial recycling doesn't work for data frame columns:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10)
d$x <- 1
d$x <- 1:2
d$x <- 1:3
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = 1:3) : 
#  replacement has 3 rows, data has 10
```

From the relevant help text ?`[<-.data.frame`, in the Arguments section:

"`value`:   A suitable replacement value: it will be repeated a **whole** number of times if necessary"

Partial recycling works for vectors though:

```
x <- d$x
x[] <- 1:3
# Warning message:
# In x[] <- 1:3 :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

x
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1
```

You can do the assignment to your data frame similarly (if you're sure it's what you want to do):

```
d$x[] <- 1:3
# Warning message:
# In d$x[] <- 1:3 :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
d
#    x
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 4  1
# 5  2
# 6  3
# 7  1
# 8  2
# 9  3
# 10 1
```

Comment: Thank you. 'store.df$weekday_id[] <- 1:7' worked. Slightly funny that the first two only worked for me by accident.